# Помогите решить проблему с передачей значений между компонентами React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Проблема в редактировании заметки

В компоненте FormToDo есть инпут для редактирования заметки он второй
Код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значение с этого инпута вытягивается в App.jsx в функцию EditToDo
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А выполняться должно по нажатию на кнопку в компоненте ToDolist при нажатии на да див поле с иконкой "Penicon" там пока стоит затычка в виде alert

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/dart95/TODO.git

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: На данной площадке принято выкладывать код текстом, а не картинками. Картинки - это не удобно.

Comment: @OliverPatterson. 
` const addTask = (userInput) => {
    if (userInput) {
      const newItem = {
        id: Math.random().toString(36),
        title: userInput,
        complete: false,
        work_in_progress: false,
        pending: true,
      };
      setTodos([...todos, newItem]);
    }
  };

  const editToDo = (userInputEdit, id, newItem) => {
    const newTodo = [...todos].map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        newItem.title = userInputEdit;
      }
    });
    setTodos([...todos, newTodo]);
  };`. editTodo должен изменять название карточки

Comment: значения берутся из следующего поля
`
const handleSubmit2 = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    editToDo(userInputEdit);
    setUserInputEdit("");
  };

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit2}>
          <input
            className="input-todo"
            type="text"
            value={userInputEdit}
            onChange={handleChange2}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
            placeholder="Редактирование заметки "
          />
          <button className="todo-btn"> Save</button>
        </form> `
Но значение в карточке не изменяется а просто добавляется пустая карточка